# How to add GUI to a finished program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've built a program in Java that's pure text or CLI. Now I would like to build a GUI on top of it.
Back when I was in school, I only learned how to build a program around a GUI and not a GUI around the program.

How would I go about doing so?

Thank you.

EDIT: Apparently I was completely misunderstood. Aside from inputting arguments, I have things like progress information and stuff which I display using strings in the CLI model. I already know the basics of building GUIs and graphical input interface.

Comment: You could start with some research, trying having a read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/, when you done there, make some sketches on paper of what you want to achieve then combine what you've learned :)

Comment: Oh, if you've separated model from view and presenter then you just have to exchange the CLI view by a GUI view ;)

Comment: " learned how to build a program around a GUI and not a GUI around the program" -- would that more schools helped you partition the two often very independent problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you write your GUI, refactor your CLI until it's not doing any actual work. That is, you have a clear barrier of separation between input gathering and data manipulation.

For example, imagine a CLI that manages some inventory. This would be bad:

```
if(command.equals("additem")) {
    int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    if(items.contains(itemNumber) { // exists, add to current
        int currentQuantity = items.get(itemNumber);
        int newQuantity = quantity + currentQuantity;
        items.put(itemNumber,newQuantity);
    } else { // doesn't exist, make new entry
        items.put(itemNumber,quantity);
    }
    continue;
}
```

It's good in that it does what it should. It's bad in that the CLI is doing the work, not some other interface. A better approach would be

```
if(command.equals("additem")) {
    int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    inventoryManager.addItem(itemNumber,quantity);
    continue;
}
```

Now all your CLI does is gather input, and pass that input into some manager.

Once EVERY command in your CLI is in the format of "gather input and pass it into some manager class", you are ready to make your GUI. When you make your GUI, you call the exact same methods you would in your CLI, you just get your data from the GUI fields instead of from the CLI!

Comment: It's been many years and after revisiting, I finally understand this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To code a GUI in Java, you most likely want to use the built-in `Swing` framework.

A quick search for "Java Swing tutorials" will reveal many helpful results, but here are some good resources to get you started:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/
- http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/

If you're serious about getting into Java GUI programming, then I highly suggest that you purchase a [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Swing-Marc-Loy/dp/0596004087/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343683745&sr=8-1) on the subject.